# Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch error on displaying data from JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, vba, foreach, type-mismatch

I'm getting stuck with the `Run-time error '13':` `Type Mismatch` error on displaying data from JSON Array. 
Getting stuck at the `home3.Cells(vp, 8) = item41("nonVariableListPrice")`. I'm trying many different ways and methods by researching google and still unable to solve the problem. May I know if this is a JSON converter problem?
 However I'm able to call the other array data from another API without any errors...
Kindly please refer to the below code:

```
vp = 7


Lastrow2 = Noutput.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

For id = 2 To Lastrow2 'make a loop call for OpenBasket API
    If Cells(id, 6).Value <> "sn?pshot" Then
            
         Dim strUrl62 As String
        
        'For search quote service API-Step1
        strUrl62 = Cells(id, 6).Value
            
        'create a method for calling HTTP services
        Set hReq62 = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                
            With hReq62
                .Open "GET", strUrl62, blnAsync, False
                'Set the headers for bypassing the API service.
                .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" & authKey
                .Send
                While hReq62.ReadyState <> 4
                    DoEvents
                Wend
                
                'wrap the response in a JSON root tag "data" to count returned objects
                strResponse62 = hReq62.ResponseText

            End With
            
        Dim Json61 As Object
        Set Json61 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse62)
    
    For Each check41 In Json61
        If check41 = "nonVariableListPrice" Then
        
        
        For Each item41 In Json61
            **home3.Cells(vp, 8) = item41("nonVariableListPrice")**
            Debug.Print item41
    
    Next item41
        Else
        
        home3.Cells(vp, 8).Value = "NO DATA"
        
    End If
    
    
    Next check41
    vp = vp + 1
```

Screenshots: 
[Error line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF8WZ.png)
[JSON Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvC6h.png)
[Runtime Error '1004'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUnxN.png)
["Left" unexpected VS "Right"expected Output in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3MaM.png)

Example JSON:

```
    {
        "associatedItems": [],
        "associatedTiedItems": [],
        "baseSkuClass": "XZ050",
        "baseSkuClassDescription": "CYBERSENSE SUBSCRIPTION",
        "baseSkuNumber": "210-AXQX",
        "brandId": "1263",
        "buildToStock": false,
        "catalogId": 18,
        "categories": [
            {
                "name": "CONFIG",
                "id": "root",
                "parentCategoryId": "-1",
                "description": "CONFIG"
            },
        ],
        "taxes": [],
        "type": "OrderCode",
        "weight": 0.0,
        "catalogSystemUri": "CFG",
        "allowChangeQuantity": true,
        "familyName": "CyberSense",
        "shipsWith": false,
        "nonVariableListPrice": 147876.912,
        "nonVariableCost": 0.0,
        "catalogCurrency": "USD",
        "nonVariableCurrency": "USD",
        "nonVariableHedgeRateUsed": 1.0,
        "isVariablePriced": true,
        "validationResult": {
            "isValid": true,
            "message": []
        },
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the JSON, it's not possible to help you without knowing the JSON structure.

Comment: Hi @RaymondWu, posted the JSON structure. thanks!

Comment: Not sure what is your `For each item411 in Json61` loop for but try `home3.Cells(vp, 8) = Json61(check41)` just below `If check41 = "nonVariableListPrice" Then` @Raiden

Comment: Hi @RaymondWu, `For each item41 in Json61` is for looping each of the `"nonVariableListPrice"` from multiple APIs. I'm calling multiple APIs for retrieving the same data from the Object '"nonVariableListPrice"'. Just tried your way `home3.Cells(vp, 8) = Json61(check41)` just below `If check41 = "nonVariableListPrice" Then` not getting the data return for the '"nonVariableListPrice"', it went to the `Else loop` with `NO DATA`.

Comment: I try to put `home3.Cells(vp, 8) = Json61(item41)` below the `For each item41 in Json61` I'm getting the `"Run-time error '1004':"` `Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: You may refer to the above screenshot named `"Runtime Error '1004'"` that I've just posted. For Each loop is a "MUST" in my condition to detect the `"nonVariableListPrice"` from multiple APIs that I going to print all the data. Just wondering if there is any way to bypass the annoying `Type Mismatch`' error that I got from the beginning.

Comment: @RaymondWu I'm adding 1 example screenshot for the unexpected and expected Output in Excel Sheet. Based on the query you had given it shows `NO DATA` for all the "RIGHT" Yellow highlighted columns. The result of "RIGHT" Yellow highlighted from the screenshot Is using `home3.Cells(vp, 8) = Json61("nonVariableListPrice")` below the `For Each item41 In Json61` . I know this is wrong and I should put `= item41` instead of `= Json61` to print each of the data from multiple APIs. But if i do so, I'm getting the `Type mismatch` error.. that's my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by multiple APIs, are you are calling the same API that returns the same JSON format ? Is that format what you posted in the question (which is also invalid because the structure is incomplete, please edit to a complete one)? And lastly, is there only 1 `nonVariableListPrice` or multiple in each API response? @Raiden

Comment: Based on the JSON, you should only need `Json61("nonVariableListPrice")` to get `147876.912`, no loop is required at all.

Comment: Hi @RaymondWu, I will paste you the full code of calling the multiple API and possibly with the complete structure of JSON tomorrow. I'm shortening it because I was afraid of the character's limit. The `nonVariableListPrice` appearing 1 time for each API I had called, that's the reason why I'm looping them.

Comment: If you refer to the above screenshot `"Left" unexpected VS "Right"` expected Output in Excel` you can see the `Open Basket Lite URL(DCQO)` columns are actually the (9) APIs that I'm calling and put into a response and convert using JSON converter and assign to `json61` as an object.

Comment: Hi @RaymondWu, the issue has been resolved. Apologies for giving the limited data in the first place as I'm very new to StackOverflow. Thanks for your tips and points that were given to me, it means a lot to me! You are right! the `"For Each loop"` is not required and I'm just creating a redundent loop for check the names of the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item41` *is a **key** in the dictionary `Json61`* and not itself a Dictionary object, so you get an error here:

```
home3.Cells(vp, 8) = item41("nonVariableListPrice")
```

You don't need to loop and check the names of the keys, since Dictionary has an `Exists` method:

```vb
Dim Json61 As Object
Set Json61 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse62)
    
If Json61.Exists("nonVariableListPrice") Then
    home3.Cells(vp, 8).Value = Json61("nonVariableListPrice")
Else
    home3.Cells(vp, 8).Value = "NO DATA"
End If
```

Slightly cleaner using a utility function:

```vb
home3.Cells(vp, 8).Value = ValueOrDefault(Json61, "nonVariableListPrice", "NO DATA")
```

Function:

```vb
Function ValueOrDefault(dict as object, k, default)
    If dict.Exists(k) Then
        ValueOrDefault = dict(k)
    Else
        ValueOrDefault = default
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: So much thanks! this resolves the problem perfectly. Now all the results are showing accordingly for each of the`"nonVariableListPrice"` from multiple APIs. That's making sense there is already a for loop for looping each of the APIs to detect the names of the keys in the first place, looks like I'm creating a redundant `"For Each"` loop to check the names of the keys.. Thanks a lot for the clear explanation and for breaking down the criteria.